# How to merge two columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to merge two columns from deferent tables and when run my query shows this error:

> Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 1 in SELECT statement

Here is my query

```
select (problems.name + department.dep_name) as m, usere.Use_name
    , emp_problems.op_date  
from usere, department, problems, emp_problems 
where usere.id = emp_problems.users_id and emp_problems.prob_id = problems.id   
and emp_problems.dup_dep_id = department.id
and emp_problems.emp_id = 37 and emp_problems.months = 11 and emp_problems.years =2020
```

Comment: Learn about sql collation: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-collation-introduction-with-collate-sql-casting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ALTER one of the columns to change the collation, or use `COLLATE` clause as

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
  MyCol1 VARCHAR(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC,
  MyCol2 VARCHAR(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI
);
```

Using `ALTER`:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable 
ALTER COLUMN MyCol2 VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC;
```

Using `COLLATE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES
('Foo', 'Bar');
/* This will throw the error */
SELECT CONCAT(MyCol1, MyCol2) FROM dbo.MyTable;

/* This won't */
SELECT CONCAT(MyCol1, MyCol2 COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC) FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

Take a look at [Set or Change the Column Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation?view=sql-server-ver15)

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57dbe57ed239512c1f0c218466dc1514)